# Android ViewPagerTabStrip Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-support-library

I am not familiar with fragments and I have created a ViewPagerTabStrip for my fragments however I have some mismatch and I dont know what to call.

PROBLEM
In the MainActivity

```
viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPager(getSupportFragmentManager()));
```

I cannot apply android.content.context to android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Please post the stacktrace

Comment: @ACluelessProgramer I havent ran it, it is mostly due to the incompatible types..explained

Comment: If you read the code Ive posted, My MainActivity extends FragmentActivity. the tabs are all extends by fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when your importing your Fragment in the Activity that extends the Fragment to choose `android.v4.app.FragmentManager`  not `android.app.FragmentManager`.  I've made this same mistake before and it took me a while to figure out.  Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

Try setting your adapter like this:

```
mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
}


/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
...
    }
```

You can go ahead and put this in your MainActivity along with the getItem() and getCount() etc.

Comment: Yeah, I have fixed that but now I still have viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPager(getSupportFragmentManager())); as a problem

Comment: nvm I fixed it I needed to call my project, can you explain it and why? viewPager.setAdapter(new com.example.app.ViewPager(getSupportFragmentManager())); it worked after i added com.example.app

Comment: Hmmm... thats strange. No I don't know why you would have to do that.  Glad you got it fixed, though.